# Android: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY

Tags: android, shared-libraries

I'm trying to use the following library in my Android app:

http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html

I donwloaded the .jar file and added it the Java Build Path, but I got the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView$GraphViewData[]
```

On further investigation, I discovered that I had to use the "uses-library" tag in the AndroidManifest under "application".

However, I don't know what to enter under android:name.

```
<uses-library android:name="com.jjoe64.graphview"></uses-library>
```

I tried this and other variations but it results in INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY installation error.

What do I do?

Thanks

Edit: Question Answered. How do I close this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. Figured it out.

I updated Eclipse's Android ADT to version 18. So I needed to rename my library folder from "lib" to "libs" for it to recognize the class path. I also removed the uses-library tag from the Manifest.

Hope this helps people in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Project properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export, check the lib jar.
That should export the lib you are using and thus you shouldn't get the error you mentioned

Answer (score 0):

Project properties->Java Build Path->Order and Export, check the lib jar.
and your effort for AndroidManifest.xml is not needed, so you can delete it.
I have the same problem when I use a third party jar.
I solved it by the two comments under your answer.