# Not able to install .apk file

Tags: android, apk

When I try to execute the .apk file I get the following error ***install_failed_missing_shared_library***.

Comment: yeah! right you should not remove your original question contents,plz just add updates

Answer (score 2):

in your command prompt cd to the path of the adb (navigate to your SDK's platform-tools/ directory)
and then execute the command

```
adb -d install path/to/your/app.apk
```

ex:

```
adb -d install C:/Users/users2/Desktop/adt-bundle-windows-x86/sdk/tools/my.apk
```

check http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html#RunningOnDevice

Comment: Hi now i am getting the following error when i try to execute the .apk file i get the following error install_failed_missing_shared_library.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10757116/android-install-failed-missing-shared-library