# How to view extracted xml files in android?

Tags: android, xml

I have extracted the code from an apk file while i am able to view the java code in eclipse i am not able to view the xml code.

The xml code is showing some garbage code.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You can decode them using a Java program - AXMLPrinter2.jar.

- [option 1](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=514412)
- [option 2](http://code.google.com/p/android4me/downloads/detail?name=AXMLPrinter2.jar&can=2&q=)

Comment: How to use it. plz explain

Answer (score 7):

Hey instead of extracting just code. use `apktool` to decompile the apk.

usage:

```
apktool d <apk_file> <folder>
```

the folder contains all the xmls resources and code too

cheers

Comment: I already did that and the extracted xml file is showing garbage values. I need to know how to resolve it.

Comment: @user1844638: When you decompile the apk I don't think it just decompile the source. It will also decompile xmls. are you getting any error while decompiling?

Comment: no i am not getting any error when i decompile. I am using these steps to decompile http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13855334/not-able-to-install-apk-file

Comment: apktool d <apk_file> <folder> this is used for decompile only. If apktool is not installed first insatall it and try to decompile with apktool only no need to follow any steps

Comment: is folder the place where the project is stored??

Comment: @user1844638 yup, <folder> contains the decompiled content.